# Update the seekbar on Tv when Chromecast from the android sender App

Tags: android, chromecast, android-seekbar

I have an custom streaming audio player to play the songs from the server and liked to integrate the chromecast with this app, now it's working fine. but here how can i update and control the seek bar from the sender App that would be reflected in receiver App and how to maintain the session for my app while casting?, because i have to be reconnected with chromecast again on same page when i come from the other app and background mode while casting audio on TV.

Please guide me the life cycle for the chromecast for stream the audio on Tv and support in background mode.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the CastVideos sample app:
https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android

It uses the Cast Companion Library that manages the state across activities:
https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android

Comment: Thanks for your response, those code is difficult to learn i am new in android so i need specific code to maintain the session as what i asked in the question and control the seek bar while casting

Comment: actually i need to be reconnected when come back from the other page or from other app while casting (But it shows as casting with device name), so pls send specific code for this kind of problem and guide me how to avoid this session problem? Thanks in Advance